# Get data from sdcard in ActionScript Mobile (Android) project?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-sdcard, flash-builder4.5

I am developing an **ActionScript for Mobile** project in which i want to **read a .txt file** from my **sdcard** and do some stuff with its data.
I am aware of how to read a file from sdcard in native android java, but i cant seem to find my way around this problem since there is no emulator in Flash Builder 4.6 like the one in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that explains how to access the SD card
http://richard-heck.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-write-file-to-android-filesystem.html

And another one that's explaining how to use ANT to push your flex app to the android simulator or device that's connected via USB 
http://flashlounge.net/workflow/2010/android-air-development-using-ant-adt-for-fdt-4/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanx a lot @pkyeck.. The first link was really helpful.. :-)

Comment: What if the user do not have sd-card and you try to access it, what will happen?